# how to read two variable as integer and char in one line in python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I input multiple variable,like integer then char then again integer in python 3.5? When I tried this as shown below(python code) its gives me an error like

> **Traceback (most recent call last):File "F:/Programming/424 - Integer Inquiry.py", line 3, in x = int(input()) ValueError: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: '300 + 3'**

like in c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int a,b;
     char ch;
     scanf("%d %c %d", &a,&ch,&d);
     return 0;
}
```

i tried it in python as:

```
x = int(input())
ch = chr(input())
y = int(input())
```

But, it doesn't work. 
I can do this in C, C++ or Java, but how can I do this in Python 3.5??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not have a `char` type, there are only strings.

```
# These are both the same
s1 = "Hello"
s2 = 'Hello'

# So are these
s3 = "a"
s4 = 'a'
```

`chr` is actually a builtin function like `int` that converts an integer to its ascii equivalent.

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

Furthermore the error you are receiving is due to the fact that you are trying to convert `"300 + 3"` to an integer which the `int` function can not evaluate.

---

What you will want to look at is using the `str.split` method to split your input.

```
inp = input("Enter words: ")
values = inp.split()
print(values) # print list of words from input
print(values[0]) # print first word

# Output
Enter words: Hello World! How are you?
['Hello', 'World!', 'How', 'are', 'you?']
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give any input to variable, below is the code

```
value=input()
list1=list()
print("You have entered:-",value)
for number in value.split():
      list1.append(number)

print(list1)
```

output of this code:

```
123 you have enter 456
You have entered:- 123 you have enter 456
['123', 'you', 'have', 'enter', '456']
```

Now you can do whatever you want.